# Separable Extension given prime characteristic

Tags: galois-theory

I am struggling with this question. I know how to answer it if $K$ is a finite field, but I don't know how to in the case that $K$ is an infinite field of characteristic $p$.

Let $K$ be an arbitrary field of characteristic $p$, and assume that $L/K$ is a finite
extension with $[L : K] = n$ and $p \not\mid n$. Show that $L/K$ is a separable extension of
fields.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $\alpha$ be an element of $L$. The minimal polynomial $f(X)$ for $\alpha$ has degree $d$ dividing $n$, hence $d$ is not divisible by $p$.

Therefore $f^{\prime}(X)=dX^{d-1}+\cdots$ is non-zero, hence $f(X)$ and $f^{\prime}(X)$ are relatively prime. This proves that $\alpha$ is separable over $K$, and since $\alpha$ was any element of $L$ this shows that $L/K$ is a separable extension.

Comment: Very nice, and way better than https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/748597/degree-of-non-separable-extension